# Captcha failing, now what?

Tags: validation, captcha

Installed a captcha on my blog, been good up until now.

There have recently been a bunch of legit-at-first-glance-but-actually-spam entries along with stuff like this:

message: IDevY7  sdbgztbczgpj
from: fmfwls

The IP changes per submission and they must be correctly filling in the captcha. Is my only option manual approval of comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is all captchas can be beaten by bots now, even reCaptcha which is a really great solution (Google) Try reCaptcha, you might have better results with that then what you are using now. I found it kept most things out when I was using it, but stuff still did get through.

Other than that look at some other non-captcha spam fighting solutions. Have you looked into [akismet](http://akismet.com)? Its a great server side solution that looks at the content and attempts to identify it as spam. Perhaps if you combine the two you may catch the majority of it.

There are various other [tricks you can try](http://tyleregeto.com/alternative-solutions-to-using-captchas) too. I'd definitely recommend checking out akismet though.

Answer (score 0):

Which captcha system are you using? Has it been broken? Have you tried recaptcha?